# running django makemigrations twice generates two migrations, one to add a field and one to alter that same field … to itself

Tags: python, django

One would expect that running `makemigrations` twice in a row would be a no-op for the second one, but in fact I get two migrations, and the second one can't be applied (an exception is thrown trying to access `None.startswith`). Output somewhat sanitized:

```
% ./manage.py makemigrations                                                                
Migrations for 'foo':
  foo/migrations/0004_foo.py
    - Add field foo to bar
% ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'foo':
  fooo/migrations/0005_alter_foo.py
    - Alter field foo on bar
```

The contents of the migrations are basically:

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="bar",
            name="foo",
            field=models.ForeignObject(
                default=1,
                from_fields=["original_id", "original_date"],
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT,
                related_name="+",
                to="foo.baz",
                to_fields=["id", "date"],
            ),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
```

for the first, and then the "alteration":

```py
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="bar",
            name="foo",
            field=models.ForeignObject(
                from_fields=("original_id", "original_date"),
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT,
                related_name="+",
                to="payment.payment",
                to_fields=("id" "date"),
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

Attempting to run the migration results in:

```
  File "/Users/wolfson/.local/share/virtualenvs/message_digest-gQFszokA/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/operations.py", line 189, in quote_name
    if name.startswith('"') and name.endswith('"'):                                                                                                            
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that in the model definition, I had this:

```py
ForeignObject(
    to=...,
    from_fields=["original_id", "original_date"],
    to_fields=["id", "date"],
    ...,
)
```

See how those are *lists*? And in the generated migrations, they're now *tuples*? Yeah. These have to be tuples, apparently!

Comment: This seems to be a known bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34824 and fixed in Django 5.0: https://github.com/django/django/commit/938170008ea48dff8f89b0839998a1eec939ddf4